# How add "external-id" parameter into AssumeRole method?

Tags: php, aws-sdk, aws-php-sdk

I'm trying to connect to another account's bucket through "AssumeRole". Through CLI everything is working (I'm just adding "External ID" through parameter "--external-id"), but through SDK - I cannot to find how to add "External ID" correctly.

Code Example:

```
$stsClient = new StsClient([
    'region' => 'us-west-2',
    'version' => 'latest',
    'credentials' => $provider
]);

$ARN = "arn:aws:iam::12345678:role/some_test_role";
$sessionName = "some-test-session-name";
$externalId = "TEST-EXTERNAL-ID"; //How to pass it into AssumeRole?

$assumeRoleResult = $stsClient->AssumeRole([
    'RoleArn' => $ARN,
    'RoleSessionName' => $sessionName
]);
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I guess something like this will work for you! ::    
$assumeRoleResult = $stsClient->AssumeRole([
    'RoleArn' => $ARN,
    'RoleSessionName' => $sessionName,
    'ExternalId' => $externalId 
]);

Answer (score 0):

As Ali Ourag said, adding that key to your array should work. If you want to see what all the options are for parameters to AssumeRole, you can check out the API definition at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-sts-2011-06-15.html#assumerole

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34087742)